# Update operation SQLite (javafx)

Tags: java, sqlite

I try to do school management app, i have done the 'add student' operation and 'delete student' operation, but a can't figure out how to do 'update operation', below here is my code for addStudent and updateStudent

```
@FXML
   private void addStudent(javafx.event.ActionEvent event){
     String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO students (id,fname,lname,email,DOB) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    try{
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

        stmt.setString(1, this.id.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, this.firstname.getText());
        stmt.setString(3, this.lastname.getText());
        stmt.setString(4, this.email.getText());
        stmt.setString(5, this.dob.getEditor().getText());

        stmt.execute();
        conn.close();

    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.getMessage();

    }
}


@FXML
private void updateStudent(javafx.event.ActionEvent event){
    String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE students SET fname=?, lname=?, email=?, DOB=? WHERE id=?"; /*setid=?...*/ /*VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)*/

    try{
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);

        stat.setString(1,this.id.getText());
        stat.setString(2,this.firstname.getText());
       stat.setString(3,this.lastname.getText());
      stat.setString(4,this.email.getText());
       stat.setString(5,this.dob.getEditor().getText());

        stat.execute();
        conn.close();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean when you say "can't figure out how to do 'update operation'" since you posted an `updateStudent` method. Tell us what you expect to happen, what actually happens and provide any errors or stack traces that are thrown.

Comment: okey, sorry, the record didnt update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without error message I can just guess.
I think there is a order problem whith your parameters. 
You set the id as the first parameter but it should be in the last position.

In "UPDATE students SET fname=?, lname=?, email=?, DOB=? WHERE id=?" the first parameter is firstname, not Id

```
 stat.setString(1,this.firstname.getText());
 stat.setString(2,this.lastname.getText());
 stat.setString(3,this.email.getText());
 stat.setString(4,this.dob.getEditor().getText());
 stat.setString(5,this.id.getText());
```